# How can I split a string into separate keys and values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following string:

```
myString = "Name:Joe Email:info@domian.com Details: I like Sushi";
```

I would like to split it out into separate variables like:

```
name = "Joe";
email = "info@domian.com";
details = "I like Sushi";
```

I tried something like the below, but it didn't account for everything.

```js
myString = "Name:Joe Email:info@domian.com Details: I like Sushi";
splitString = myString.split(':');
myName = splitString[1];
myEmail = splitString[2];
myFood = splitString[3];

console.log('Name: ', myName);
console.log('Email: ', myEmail);
console.log('Food: ', myFood);
```

I'm wondering if there might be a creative way to do this in JS? Thanks.

Comment: What does "didn't account for everything" mean? Please revise to be more specific about what problem you're facing.

Comment: That input format is going to be difficult to break down due to its inconsistent use of spaces to delimit name/value pairs. I'd suggest that your time would be better spent improving the way that string is serialised, perhaps by using JSON instead, than spending time hacking the string in to the format you need using JS.

Comment: I've enhanced your code and added a snippet so it's more apparent what the deficiencies are. Looks like you want to work backward from the colons to remove a word.

Comment: Like Rory McCrossan implies, you may be asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). Can you fix the problem upstream?

Comment: Thanks all. It's an odd situation where I am using fullcalendar.io and an ICAL feed as the source . This data is in the description field of the ICS file that is pulled from form data. So, I was looking for a way to make it more manageable as I want to make a pretty looking popup with the data.

Comment: If you know the keys, and can guaranteer the order there in, you could get the values using a few `indexOf` and `substr`'s. Let me know if you'd like an example since there's already an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will turn your string into an object with key/value pairs using `match()` and `split()`. You can then access the variables using the object, like `obj.name` or `obj.email`. There may be a way to fix my regex so that the `.shift()` method isn't necessary, but it works nonetheless.

```js
let myString = "Name:Joe Email:info@domian.com Details: I like Sushi";

let keys = myString.match(/\w+:/g)
let values = myString.split(/\w+:/);
values.shift(); // remove first item which is empty
let obj = {};
keys.forEach((key, index) => {
  obj[key.replace(":", "").toLowerCase()] = values[index].trim()
})

console.log(obj)

// access variables like obj.name or obj.email
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
myString = "Name:Joe Email:info@domian.com Details: I like Sushi";    
splitString = myString.split(':');    
myName = splitString[1].split(' ')[0];
myEmail = splitString[2].split(' ')[0];
myFood = splitString[3]

console.log(myName);
console.log(myEmail);
console.log(myFood);
```

If you want to get rid of the space in front of "I like Sushi":

```
details = splitString[3].split(' '); 
myDetails = details[1] +' '+ details[2] +' '+ details[3]; console.log(myDetails);
```

Comment: I'm revisiting this question I asked. I was wondering what the [0] does in your code. I thought it was an indexOf of some sort, but wasn't sure. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, [0] is indexing. This line of code: splitString[1].split(' ')[0] 
uses [0] to select the first element of the list created.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myString = "Name:Joe Email:info@domian.com Details: I like Sushi";
var arr = myString.replace(/:\s/g, ':').split(" "),
  obj = {};
// .replace(/:\s/g,':') Or .replace(/[:\s]/g,':') whichever works better
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var item = arr[i],
    arr2 = item.split(":"),
    key = arr2[0].toLowerCase();
  obj[key] = arr2[1];
}
console.log(obj["email"]);
//info@domain.com
console.log(obj["details"]);
//I like Sushi
```

Comment: Protip: you can delete your answer and continue editing until it works, then undelete.

Comment: I fixed the 4 basic typographical issues in your snippet for you. Please at least hit the 'Run' button in a snippet to test it before posting the answer.